# PHP: Space issue

Tags: php

(made a new question, as instead of having 2 "questions" in my other question)

I am making an PM system for my users.

In the recipient field you type in a full name. When you submit i want to make sure it's the right user he sends to.

And im having a space issue. If I only enter a space in the recipient field, it will return all users name´s inside my "Who did you mean?", in the table. How can i prevent this, and not run the query its empty or only contain spaces? (a nice way)

Here's my code:

```
$mot = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['mottagare']);
list($firstname, $lastname) = array_map('ucfirst', explode(' ', $mot, 2));
$qur = mysql_query("
 SELECT id, firstname, lastname, 
 (firstname = '$firstname' AND lastname = '$lastname') AS full FROM users 
 WHERE (firstname = '$firstname' AND lastname='$lastname') 
 OR (firstname LIKE '$firstname%' AND lastname LIKE '$lastname%')
 OR firstname LIKE '$firstname%' OR lastname LIKE '$firstname%'
 ORDER BY (firstname = '$firstname' AND lastname='$lastname') DESC");

 if(mysql_num_rows($qur) == 1){

 $get = mysql_fetch_array($qur);
    if($get["full"] == 1){
    echo $get["id"];
    }else{
     echo "Did you mean: ".$get["firstname"]." ".$get["lastname"]." ?";
    }
 }elseif(mysql_num_rows($qur) > 1){
    while($get = mysql_fetch_array($qur)) {
       $name[] = $get["firstname"]." ".$get["lastname"];
   }

   if(count($name) > 1) {
       echo 'Who did you mean?<br>';
   } else {
       echo 'Did you mean: ';
   }
   echo implode('<br>', $name);

 }
```

Comment: your query gonna be terrible slow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add something like this after the first line of your script:

```
$mot = trim($mot);
if(strlen($mot) < 1)
    return;
```

`trim` will remove all leading and trailing spaces, and the next lines check if there is nothing entered and return if so.

Comment: Checking string length is your best route, 3 is a good number to require before before running any commands.

Comment: You need to have the trim in there as well to make sure there isn't just a space.  And 3 is a good number, but for searching a small list you may want to just leave it at 1, it all depends on the data.

Comment: Returning early like this could make it difficult to figure out what's going on in a code block this large.

Comment: True, it might be better to put the rest of the code in an else statement.  It all depends on if this is being done in a function or on it's own and how the rest of the code is laid out.  That's why I just said something like that.

Comment: I dont really understand what you Webnet is reffering to, but Im not having a small user list, but ok big. Is this bad then?

Comment: @Johnson, what Webnet is saying is you shouldn't start searching until at least 3 characters (that are not spaces) have been entered.  This makes sense for ajax calls where each keystroke results in a request, but I don't believe what Webnet is suggesting is useful in this case since you're already making a round trip to do your searching.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [trim](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) function to strip all white space, then check the length of the string, if it doesn't have at least one character, then don't perform the search.

```
if (strlen(trim($name)) > 0) {
   // perform search here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just check if `$firstname` is `''` before doing the query.

Comment: This answer reminds me of http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/Double-Spaced.aspx... who will take care of `' '`?

Comment: @delnan: The call to `explode()` will.

Comment: This is prone to error since it doesn't cover all the cases.  And using explode() is the wrong function for the job considering the amount of overhead it incurs to split compared to a trim.

Answer (score 0):

Don't put `anything LIKE '$firstname%'` in your SQL query if `trim($firstname)` is empty.

Comment: I won't down-vote, but it would be wiser not to perform the search at all if it's empty since it saves a hit to the database.

Comment: @Soviut: the search happens on two variables. One variable being empty does not mean the other is. Of course, if there's neither a firstname nor a lastname, the search function should not have been called in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

You could first of all delete all spaces with the trim() function.
After doing it you could just look if the string is empty with the empty() function that check whatever the variable is NULL or empty string ('').
At least it is more elegant than put a `if ($string === '')`.